# What happen to pointers when vectors need more memory and realocate memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management

When vector needs more memory it will reallocate memory somewhere, I don't know where yet! and then pointers become invalid, is there any good explanation on this?

I mean where they go, what happen to my containers? ( not linked list ones )

Comment: Some code to demonstrate this would be useful...

Comment: I think this might be a problem: `std::vector<int> foo(10); int *ip = &foo.front();`. Reallocation might invalidate `*ip`, right? However, you shouldn't abuse std::vector this way. Use iterators.

Comment: Protip: Use indices not pointers.

Comment: @zerm Reallocation invalidates iterators, too. By the way, it won't invalidate `*ip`, of course, only `ip`.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, sorry, you are absolutely right in both aspects.

Comment: @ChristianRau How can `*ip` as expression be valid if `ip` as a pointer is invalid? :)

Comment: Oh, do you mean that if you store the value of `*ip` somewhere it will be valid?

Comment: @Michael I just meant it doesn't invalidate the object pointed to by `ip`, but the pointer. But of course dereferencing the invalid pointer is also invalid. I guess I just was nit-picky where I shouldn't have been. You could say I didn't refer to the expression `*ip`, but the expression's value.

Comment: @ChristianRau, ah, that was my second guess (hairsplittingwise, I think you still worded the first part is prone to attacks :))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Short answer:** Everything will be fine. Don't worry about this and get back to work.

**Medium answer:** Adding elements to or removing them from a vector invalidates all iterators and references/pointers (possibly with the exception of removing from the back). Simple as that. Don't refer to any old iterators and obtain new ones after such an operation. Example:

```
std::vector<int> v = get_vector();

int & a = v[6];
int * b = &v[7];
std::vector<int>::iterator c = v.begin();
std::advance(it, 8);

v.resize(100);
```

Now `a`, `b` and `c` are all invalid: You cannot *use* `a`, and you cannot *dereference* `b` or `c`.

**Long answer:** The vector keeps track of dynamic memory. When the memory is exhausted, it allocates a new, larger chunk elsewhere and copies (or moves) all the old elements over (and then frees up the old memory, destroying the old objects). Memory allocation and deallocation is done by the *allocator* (typically `std::allocator<T>`), which in turn usually invokes `::operator new()` to fetch memory, which in turn usually calls `malloc()`. Details may vary and depend on your platform. In any event, any previously held references, pointers or iterators are no longer valid (presumably because they refer to the now-freed memory, though it's not specified in the standard *why* they're invalid).

Comment: But… what do you mean "everything will be fine"? I thought the OP considered using pointers, pointing to the vector data? I think everything will only be fine if he parts with the idea.

Comment: I don't think you answer the actual question, which was about pointers to vector data, acquired before a reallocation.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: the OP's question is sufficiently vague that it could easily just be an idle musing about the implementation details (she's concerned about the details of the reallocation), and hence there's nothing to actually worry about. The longer answers provide details that explain why invalidation happens, so I hope all bases are covered.

Comment: Well, I still agree with the downvoter (I assume Macmade is) that you should've mentioned what would happen with pointers. Or at least having question worded like that I'd rather avoid saying everything will be fine. I mean, the short answer is the only part that raises concern.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Pointers and references essentially amount to the same: dereference the pointer and you get a reference, take the address of the reference and you get the pointer. So "references are invalidated" contains all the information. I added "pointers" explicitly, though, to be safe.

Comment: Effectively, I am the downvoter, but there's nothing personal. I'm a C programmer, and I know I'm pretty rusty with C++. This answer is well formed, you explain important things, etc. But the questions was about pointers. Even if pointers shouldn't be used in such a case, with C++, I think you should mention why, rather than speaking about references, vector internals, etc... It may be obvious to you, but I think it's not the case for the guy who posted the question. So try to focus on the question itself, and try to understand why the guy is actually asking this.

Comment: That said, I would be happy to turn my downvote to an upvote. I think you just need to explain why it's dangerous to get (and possibly store) pointers from vector entries. Basically, it's the same as storing a pointer, in pure C, to a dynamic array entry, and then reallocating that array. But IMHO you have to mention it, as the question was actually about this.

Comment: @Macmade: No worries, your objection is appreciated. I have indeed a hard time understanding the OP (who hasn't communicated at all past the OP itself); I would be happy to amend my answer if further clarification is needed. Pointers and references are essentially interchangeable for the purpose of invalidation (see my previous comment), and I added a word to that extent. By experience, though, there are sometimes SO questions which ask for things that the user shouldn't have to know, if I see what I mean, and I have a feeling that this is one of those situations. It's just my take, though!

Comment: @Macmade: Of course -- but that's really essentially the same as storing a reference: `int & a = v[6]; int * b = &v[7]; v.resize(100);` Now `a` and `b` are invalid. `&a` is a pointer and `*b` is a reference which both suffers the same problem. I updated the post!

Comment: I still find the "everything will be fine" bit a little misleading. :X I think in the context of "I have pointers to vector elements", "that's fine" isn't too good.

Comment: From a C perspective, take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/1392643 Of course, it won't work, and it's dangerous to code this way. But I think the OP is confused about the used of vectors, and was actually asking if such a kind of code would be OK, when using vectors...

Comment: _everything will be fine_ , actually i want to know for sake of knowledge , but thanks for mediam and long answer , i wish i could accept all answers , tnx

Answer (score 5):

When you add or remove items from a `vector`, all iterators (and pointers) to items within it are invalidated. If you need to store a pointer to an item in a vector, then make the vector `const`, or use a different container.

It shouldn't matter to you where the vector stores things. You don't need to do anything, just let it do its job.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `std::vector`, the class takes care of all the details regarding memory allocation, pointers, resizing and so on.

The `vector` class exposes its contents through iterators and references. Mutations of the vector will potentially invalidate iterators and references because reallocation may be necessary.

It is valid to access the contents using pointers because the `vector` class guarantees to store its elements at contiguous memory locations. Clearly any mutation of the list will potentially invalidate any pointers to its contents, because of potential reallocation. Therefore, if you ever access an element using pointers, you must regard those pointers as invalid once you mutate the vector. In short the same rules apply to pointers to the contents as do to references.

If you want to maintain a reference to an item in the vector, and have this reference be valid even after mutation, then you should remember the index rather than a pointer or reference to the item. In that case it is perfectly safe to add to the end of the vector and your index value still refers to the same element.

Comment: You can access an internal pointer using &vect[0]... Not advised but quite possible.

Comment: @WillBickford That's the blowing your entire leg off part of Bjarne's famous quote.

Comment: I use `&vect.front()` some times: E.g. storing OpenGL vertices inside a `std::vector<float>` and working with that. However, eventually some OpenGL functions require a `float*`, so just pass `&vect.front()`.

Comment: @David my point was that you do have access, despite what this answer claims.

Comment: The question was: what about existing pointers to vector data. Not about vector internals.

Comment: @WillBickford Only if you abuse references.

Comment: @Macmade You aren't meant to hold pointers to the internals of the vector. As soon as you do that then you need to know about vector internals. So how can the question be about anything other than internals once you start holding pointers to the internals.

Comment: For sure... Would be nice to explain him that specific case, and the possible issues when using pointers, IMHO.

Comment: @David Most times the only thing you have to know is that the data is stored contigously (and even that you don't always have to know), and that is a fact you always know (assuming you know that you are working in standard C++). I would definitely not call something abuse when the standard guarantees its behaviour. What is bad in making a pointer to a reference, that's not abuse in any way.