# C++ exc_bad_access accessing string field from pointed-to object in unordered_map

Tags: c++, vector, exc-bad-access, unordered-map

I'm trying to maintain a fast-access vector in the following manner:

MyClass.h:

```
class MyClass{
private:
std::vector<Stuff> myStuffList;
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string,Stuff*> myStuffListIndex;
...
public:
void addToStuffList(std::string key,Stuff stuff);

};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
...
void MyClass::addToStuffList(std::string name, Stuff stuff){
  myStuffList.push_back(stuff);//our man is guaranteed to be at tail 
  myStuffListIndex[name] = &myStuffList[myStuffList.size()-1];//store 
  //pointer to object that we just copy-constructed at tail of list
}
```

Stuff.h:

```
class Stuff{
private:
  std::string name;
public:
  Stuff();
  Stuff(const Stuff&);
  Stuff& operator=(const Stuff&);
  ...

};
```

Stuff.cpp:

```
Stuff::Stuff() : name(""){}
Stuff::Stuff(const Stuff& other){
  if(this != &other){
    this->name = other.name;
  }
}
Stuff& Stuff::operator=(const Stuff& other){
  if(this != &other){
    this->name = other.name;
  }
}
std::string Stuff::getName(){
  return name;//exc_bad_access triggered here
}
```

Later, when I try to access items from the vector via the map I get an apparently intermittent exc_bad_access error as follows:

```
void methodA(){
  Stuff localStuff;
  myClassInstance.addToStuffList("mostrecentstuff",localStuff);
}
...
void methodB(){
  //different method now, localStuff would be out of scope but 
  //shouldn't matter since we passed by value in addToStuffList, right?
  Stuff* pStuff = myStuffListIndex["mostrecentstuff"];
  std::cout << "Hello, my name is " << pStuff->getName() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
  methodA();
  methodB();
}
```

Why does an access of pStuff->getName() throw exc_bad_access?

Comment: Do not store pointers to the vector data, and have the vector resize itself.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261037/what-happen-to-pointers-when-vectors-need-more-memory-and-realocate-memory.

Comment: A side question -- why do you need to write a user-defined copy constructor and assignment op for `Stuff`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the example Stuff doesn't, but my actual project does; I figured the trouble might have come from a mistake in the cc or operator=

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what do mean 'have the vector resize itself'?  Do you need to call resize manually after push_back?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are holding onto pointers within the vector's data.  When the vector is resized using `push_back`, those pointers may become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by PaulMcKenzie, a vector can be resized, and if it is, it can be relocated at a different address. Then all pointers to previous vector items become broken.

You should never keep pointers to items in std containers, but for vectors, you can keep their indices.

You would have :

```
std::vector<Stuff> myStuffList;
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string,int> myStuffListIndex;
```

and

```
myStuffList.push_back(ability);//our man is guaranteed to be at tail 
myStuffListIndex[name] = myStuffList.size() - 1;//store
```

If your application is mutithreaded, you will have to protect above code with a mutex

Comment: ah, that would explain it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How does `std::vector` works?
It has a capacity. When this capacity is reached and you ask for the insertion of a new item, memory is reallocated with extra storage to hold this item. `std::vector` then moves its content from the first memory location to the newly allocated one.

Thus, your design is broken (you'ld need to update the map at each vector resize).

Then, concerning your test case, since you only perform one insertion, the pointer to the vector element is still valid. But looking at your `addToStuffList()` method, I see:

```
void MyClass::addToStuffList(std::string name, Stuff stuff){
    myStuffList.push_back(ability);//our man is guaranteed to be at tail 
    myStuffListIndex[name] = &myStuffList[myStuffList.size()-1];//store 
    //pointer to object that we just copy-constructed at tail of list
}
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
myStuffList.push_back(stuff);
```

What is `ability`?

Comment: ability was a copy-paste error, sorry.  Yes, it should have been stuff