# Can't explain why pointers become dangling when creating a vector of vectors of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dangling-pointer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass(int num) : val_(num) {}
    int val_;
    int val() const { return val_; }
};

// Given a vector of vector of numbers, this class will generate a vector of vector of pointers
// that point to SomeClass.
class Generator {
public:
    vector<SomeClass> objects_;
    vector<vector<SomeClass*> > Generate(const vector<vector<int> >& input) {
        vector<vector<SomeClass*> > out;
        for (const auto& vec : input) {
            out.push_back({});
            for (const int num : vec) {
                SomeClass s(num);
                objects_.push_back(s);
                out.back().push_back(&objects_.back());
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    Generator generator;
    auto output = generator.Generate({{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}});
    for (const auto& vec : output) {
        for (const auto* obj : vec) {
            printf("%d ",obj->val());
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `Generate` method in the `Generator` class will simply convert the vector of vector of `int`s to a vector of vector of pointers to `SomeClass`.

`SomeClass` is simply a container for a simple `int` value with a getter method.

I would expect the following output:

```
2 3
4 5
6
```

However, I get the following output:

```
junk_integer junk_integer
4 5
6
```

It seems the pointers in the first row become dangling pointers. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: When `objects_` resizes to allow pushing back new elements, can you guess what happens to all of the existing pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happen to pointers when vectors need more memory and realocate memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261037/what-happen-to-pointers-when-vectors-need-more-memory-and-realocate-memory)

Comment: You want an array of pointers to what kind of objects? Are these heap objects or stack objects? If the former, what part of the code is responsible for their allocation and deletion? If the latter, when do these objects go out of scope? Is there a possibility a pointer will live longer than the object it points to? These are questions you *must* answer when you create a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing pointers into a `vector`, then adding elements to the vector.  Since you're not reserving enough space for all the elements you're adding, when the vector resizes it invalidates all the pointers to the old data.

You'll either have to reserve enough space before storing the pointers, store the pointers after you've stored everything in the vector you need to store, or not store pointers (maybe store an index, instead).

Answer (score 1):

All operations that increase the number of elements in a `std::vector`, including `push_back()`, invalidates all iterators (including pointers) that refer to elements of the vector, if the resizing results in a change of vector capacity.

Your code is doing

```
objects_.push_back(s);
out.back().push_back(&objects_.back());
```

within a loop.   Every call of `objects_.push_back()` invalidates iterators of `objects_`, and therefore can result in `out.back()` containing invalid (dangling) pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing pointers to objects contained in `generator.objects_`. Some of them become dangling pointers when you call `push_back()` on that.

In general, storing pointers to objects in a `std::vector` is a bad idea.