# How to access element(having a unique identifier) in a vector using a map in constant time?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map, constant-time

I am having a class `Person`, which has a vector of another class `Badge`(with a unique Id). To access all the elements in the vector, I can iterate over the elements, which takes O(n) time, n being the size of the vector. I wanted to do it in constant time, so I created a map, with `Badge` ids as keys and pointer to `Badge` as values. Here, the pointer points to an element of the vector.
More specifically:

```
class Badge
{
public:
    Badge(string, int);
    const int& getBadgeId() const;
    const string& getBadgeName() const;
    int getRoyaltyPoints() const;
    void setRoyaltyPoints(int royaltyPoints);

private:
    int badgeId;
    string badgeName;
    int royaltyPoints;
    int getUniqueBadgeId();
};

class Person
{
public:
    Person(string);
    const unordered_map<int, Badge*>& getBadgeMap() const;
    const vector<Badge>& getBadges() const;
    const string& getName() const;
    const string& getPersonId() const;
    void addBadge(Badge&);
    void updateRoyalty(Badge&, int);

private:
    string personId;
    string name;
    vector<Badge> badges;
    unordered_map<int, Badge*> badgeMap;
    string getUniquePersonId();
};
```

The functions involved:

```
/* Adds a badge to the badges collection and updates the map */
void Person::addBadge(Badge &badge)
{
    this->badges.push_back(badge);
    this->badgeMap[badge.getBadgeId()] = &this->badges.back();
    //this->badgeMap[badge.getBadgeId()] = &this->badges[this->badges.size() - 1];
}

/* Updates the royalty points in a badge */
void Person::updateRoyalty(Badge &badge, int newValue)
{
    Badge* bd = this->badgeMap[badge.getBadgeId()];
    bd->setRoyaltyPoints(newValue);
}
```

The complete code can be found here: [https://www.ideone.com/hjUT6e](https://www.ideone.com/fork/hjUT6e)

On running the function, most of the times, a runtime error is encountered. Sometimes, the code works as expected, and other times, the `updateRoyalty()` function has no effect on the royalty points, which means it's as good as the function wasn't called at all.

Is there any way to address this weird behavior? I can think of two ideas:

1) Use `std::find()` function to search for the element in the vector and overload the `=` operator. But it takes O(n) time as well

2) In place of `Badge *`, use `Badge` as the value in the `unordered_map`. There are two problems here. First, Badge has no constructor called `Badge()`, it has a parameterized constructor. So the compiler complains. Second, I need to overload `[]` operator, write my own hash function. I am fairly new to C++, so trying to keep things simple here(if possible, language independent).

Kindly let me know how can I achieve this

Thank you

EDIT: The question has been marked duplicate and closed. The duplicate question [What happen to pointers when vectors need more memory and realocate memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261037/what-happen-to-pointers-when-vectors-need-more-memory-and-realocate-memory) is a totally different question. It's related to resizing the vector memory, whereas this is about storing pointer(as a value in map) to a vector element. I request to reopen this question.

Comment: A lookup in a `std::map` is *not* constant time. It's logarithmic in the size of the container.

Comment: Just a thought, but suppose each badge has one instance, but it is in a shared pointer. You create them in a vector of shared pointer to badge. You add the shared pointer to the map. And if you have a badge, you do not need to look it up anyway (because you already have it -- it's a shared pointer, but that doesn't matter).

Comment: @Jesper Juhl They said unordered_map in at least one place, I'll assume that's what they meant.

Comment: `this->badgeMap[badge.getBadgeId()] = &this->badges.back();` -- First, you don't need to specify `this->` in the member function.  Second, this is highly dangerous, since you're storing pointers to vector elements -- if that vector resizes, those pointers get invalidated, and your map now has invalid pointers.  Thus this may be the reason for the erratic behavior of your program.

Comment: @kenny, That still Average case: constant, worst case: linear in size.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: Yes the worst case is in the order of linear in the container size, which happens in case of a bad hash function. Since on an average, it is constant, I was vouching for the average case.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom: It's unordered_map as mentioned in code and text.
If there's a vector of shared pointer to badges, do we need to keep the badges separately in another vector(a shared pointer is still a pointer)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I think that's the issue. Just looking for a better way, someway to address the issue.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Change `std::vector` to `std::list` and see if your code works.  The `std::list` iterators are not invalidated if you add or remove elements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks a ton! This seems to work. One final question though .. is this a good design? Can it be made better?